# Camera access on DJI Osmo Pocket via DJI iOS SDK

Tags: swift, dji-sdk

I'm trying to access my DJI Pocket camera from iOS application, using DJI SDK and Swift.
The product.camera always returns nil, while .gimbal, for example, returned ok.

May be the SDK detected my device wrong, because product.model returns "Osmo Mobile", which has no built-in camera.
Is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the DJI-SDK doesn't have support for Osmo Pocket.